# Internal Builder: Cannot run program "g++": The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: eclipse, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

```
****** Internal Builder is used for build               ******
g++ -ot1.o ..\t1.cpp
Internal Builder: Cannot run program "g++": The system cannot find the file specified.

Build error occurred, build is stopped
```

I am new to eclipse, on windows XP, want to run c/c++ progms + linux build (cygwin is installed with needed packages)
Above said error is coming and builds fails! Please kindly suggest.

Edit: appends to path env variable as `e:\cygwin\bin;`

This is for ref:

[image]

Comment: Put `g++` in your PATH, so Eclipse can find it.

Comment: Does `g++` run correctly from a cygwin command-line?

Comment: yes g++ run from command-line ..

Comment: to: pajton  - Where exactly? to system path variable or in eclipse n like - e:\cygwin\bin\g++ ?

Comment: To system `PATH` variable append necessary path: `PATH=blablabla;...;e:\cygwin\bin\ `

Comment: i did it already.. also i have set  in Project-> Properties -> c/c++ build -> environment - PATH as ${PATH}

Comment: how eclipse reads this system path ? also i have see make file generated automatically ... but i dont where is the problem exactly

Comment: facing the same problem. can't solve after all these steps.

Comment: @C-xC-t I added an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

How did you [setup your Cygwin toolchain in your Eclipse CDT](http://wyding.blogspot.com/2009/04/setup-cygwin-toolchain-in-eclipse-cdt.html)?
(from the [Alex Wu](http://www.blogger.com/profile/08995821762316908100)'s excellent blog post in [Alex's Tech Blog](http://wyding.blogspot.com/))

> 1/ Install the Cygwin properly, you need following packages:

```
binutils
gcc
gcc-core
gcc-g++
gcc-mingw-core
gcc-mingw-g++
make
gdb (needed if you want to support debug in eclipse)
```

> you can check your cygwin installation using the '`cygcheck -c`' command

[image]

> 2/  Add `%cygwin%\bin` to your env `PATH`, then open the eclipse. you will find the cygwin tool chain will be shown when you open a new c/cpp project wizard.

[image]

3/ Configure the GDB.

Go to `Windows->Preference->C/C++ -> Debug -> Common Source Lookup`.
Add following 'Path mapping':

```
\cygdrive\c -> c:\
\cygdrive\d -> d:\ 
other drives if any .......
```

[image]

Comment: thx for your reply VonC

I have done all the steps you mentioned but still getting same build error :(

Comment: @Rupali: sorry to read that. There must be some other cause in your configuration which causes that. I will keep looking on my end.

Comment: thanks...plz let me know if you need any other info ..m also trying

Comment: +1 for the work, but unfortunately it does not solve the problem, I saw the PATH for exe from ProcessExplorer  and it has all the paths it requires. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same error; it was my first time using eclipse with cygwin. I am fairly new to eclipse as well but I was impressed with how powerful it was. It is unfortunate that this question was asked almost a year ago. In the interim, the software may have changed so much that my advice below may be something of an anachronism as far as this question is concerned.

I am using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Helios Service Release 2
version 1.3.2.20110218-0812

uname says that the Cygwin version is CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64

After following the (often obsolete) advice of many web posts on this issue, two things finally seemed to make it work. My sysadmin, who alone has privileges to perform software installations, needed to increase my access privileges to the cygwin/bin folder, which now stands as Read and Execute. Second, in eclipse I changed the type of builder to External: File>Properties C/C++ Build, Builder type: External builder. Build now works, though not without throwing some warnings. I am still confused about many of the intricacies of the installation, and I'm not sure why switching to an external builder made such a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @pajton one needs to correct Eclipse's expectation of the Cygwin binary path from `c:\cygwin\usr\bin` to `c:\cygwin\bin` as Cygwin authors changed to mounting /usr/bin off the latter.

I needed to change the Eclipse's addition of the Cygwin binary directory to PATH from `c:\cygwin\usr\bin` to `c:\cygwin\bin` in two configuration locations of my developer build Juno 20120322-1740:

- Project Properties / C/C++ Build / Environment
- Run / Run Configurations... / Environment

I also changed the path to a shell interpreter in the discovery option `Compiler invocation command` from `sh` to `c:\cygwin\bin\dash.exe`,

- Project Properties / C/C++ Build / Discovery Options / Cygwin C Compiler
- Project Properties / C/C++ Build / Discovery Options / Cygwin C++ Compiler

This allowed to automatically populate include directories and built-in macros in Project Properties / C/C++ General / Paths and Symbols.

Because only Cygwin-built programs such as `bash.exe`, `dash.exe` resolve Cygwin-style portable symbolic links, I changed compiler invocation commands from `gcc` to `gcc-4` and from `g++` to `g++-4`,

- Project Properties / C/C++ Build / Settings / Tool Settings / Cygwin C++ Compiler
- Project Properties / C/C++ Build / Settings / Tool Settings / Cygwin C Compiler
- Project Properties / C/C++ Build / Settings / Tool Settings / Cygwin C++ Linker

Perhaps, this will be done automatically soon as I see a change in the git repository claiming to address the issue,

- [Bug 364733 - Internal Builder does not work with Cygwin toolchain](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364733)

As I investigated my issue, I went to Help / Install New Software... / Juno / Programming Languages / C/C++ Development Tools.

As I tried to upgrade the selected piece I got an unclear message saying that the requested upgrade was required by other parts.  When I pressed "Finish", I received a prompt to restart.  I do not know if I upgraded my CDT with these actions.

If you want to catch access violations at run time, create an external tool entry in Run / External Tools... / Configure External Tools.  Specify `c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe` as the program, `${workspace_loc:/PROJECT_NAME/CONFIG_NAME}` such as `${workspace_loc:/test/Release}` as the working directory and the command option followed by the program name such as `-c "./test.exe"` in the arguments.  I found that `c:\cygwin\bin\dash.exe` does not route the stack trace produced by the Cygwin DLL to the stderr caught by Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix this is to go to

```
project properties / c/c++ build / settings / tool settings / cygwin C compiler
```

and change the command to

```
sh -c 'whatever was already there'
```

This will use **sh** to invoke the command, and thus it will resolve cygwin links.  You will also have to do this for the assembler and linker.   Of course you also have to make sure your path points to c:\cygwin\bin before starting eclipse.