# Constant Makefile Error

Tags: c++, makefile

I can't get this makefile error to go away. I have tried every syntax on earth and I can't figure out what is wrong.

My makefile reads:

```
huffmanCodeGenerator: main.o
g++ -o huffmanCodeGenerator main.o 

main.o: main.cpp ReadFile.h HuffmanCode.h ConstructTree.h WriteFile.h
g++ -c main.cpp

ReadFile.o: ReadFile.cpp ReadFile.h
g++ -c ReadFile.cpp

HuffmanCode.o: HuffmanCode.cpp HuffmanCode.h 
g++ -c HuffmanCode.cpp

ConstructTree.o: ConstructTree.cpp ConstructTree.h
g++ -c ConstructTree.cpp

WriteFile.o: WriteFile.cpp WriteFile.h
g++ -c WriteFile.cpp

clean:
&nbps rm *.o huffmanCodeGenerator
```

I have all of those files in my directory and I keep getting

> error 2 - the system cannot find the file specified.

Here is a screenshot of my directory and error:
[image: makefile error]

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I don't care how pretty or how correct the syntax is. As long as it makes.

Comment: make on windows - probably a recipe for disaster. What version of make specifically are you running ? What version and build (mingw/cygwin/other) of gcc are you using ?

Comment: It looks like it cannot find `g++` itself.  Is `g++` in your `PATH`?

Comment: And once you get past this hurdle, you're going to need to list a bunch more object files on the first two lines of your `Makefile`, I think.  (ie. more than just `main.o`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First problem I see is that your first two lines are incorrect. Linker needs all the object files and not just main.o to link them together.

Secondly, are you sure your Windows knows the path to g++? What happens if you try g++ --help in cmd, for example? (Not sure about this though, I run it like that in Unix).

Thirdly, this looks similar to your problem: [Internal Builder: Cannot run program "g++": The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606740/internal-builder-cannot-run-program-g-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-spec)

This [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/32205-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-dev-cpp/): leads to a conclusion that you need to:
1) have g++.exe in your current folder or
2) have it on your PATH

Comment: I think windows will probably want `g++ /?` instead of `--help` if its like other windows cmd line programs.

Comment: The argument to `g++` almost doesn't matter. Either it spits out some g++ related message or it spits out something indicating that it wasn't recognized as a valid command.

Comment: Yes, I left out the all of the other object files for the linker, that was part of the problem. The other part was minGW, I uninstalled and reinstalled it and everything worked out. I think it may have just been out of date. I haven't used it in a while. Thanks for your help!